# "unit and quantity abstractions" vs "units and quantities abstractions"

Tags: grammatical-number

As a non-native speaker I currently have a doubt about something. I am writing a technical note about units of measurements (kilogram, meter, second...) and physical quantities (mass, length, time) for software (and I am talking about abstractions in software architecture) and I am note entirely sure whether I should write :

- Unit and quantity abstractions
- Units and quantities abstractions

when talking about "the software abstractions of units and quantities". Is only one of them grammatically correct? Or if both of them can be correct, what is the difference and which one should I pick?